# Laravel - Storing and Setting up Array in Controller

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I am a beginner programmer in Laravel, please guide me through here thank you.

What I want is to Store this data to an array and setup this code to an array but I have no clue..

Here is my ***Controller***

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'city' => 'required'

    ]); 


   $citi = new City;
   $citi->city = $request->input('city');
   $citi->save();

   return redirect('/lugar')->with('success', 'Data Inserted');
}
```

Here is a piece of my ***View*** Code which will get the array

```
        <td> {{Form::text('city[]', '', ['class' => 'form-control name_list', 'placeholder' => 'Add Country'])}} </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily return an array in the `with()` function so your code will be something like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'city' => 'required'

    ]); 


   $citi = new City;
   $citi->city = $request->input('city');
   $citi->save();

   return redirect('/lugar')->with(['status' => 'success', 'data' => $citi]);
}
```

Comment: What if I want to implode the $citi->city = $request->input('city'); ?

Comment: It is probably because you are redirecting and not returning the view you need to return a view to use it in the blade

Comment: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given   .... my error

Comment: plus, I have no 'status nor 'data' functions here **return redirect('/lugar')->with(['status' => 'success', 'data' => $citi]);**